# Live Reload, Hot Reload, and Remote Debugging all unavailable

Tags: react-native, remote-debugging, expo, create-react-native-app

Why is Live Reload, Hot Reload, and Remote Debugger all unavailable? I've tried

1. Reloading JS Bundle
2. Restarting the simulator
3. Restarting packager
4. Restarting packager and clearing cache
5. Resetting the simulator
6. Restarting the computer

Prior to this, everything was working fine. I'm relatively new to the React Native development environment. Is there a place to look (a command or a log file or something) that may have more information figure out what the issue is?

For reference, my app was created using the `create-react-native-app` command.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my own problem. For some reason the `.expo/settings.json` had `dev: true` even though this wasn't reflecting anywhere in the UI. Diffing file trees of the current project with older versions solved my problem.

```
4c4
<   "dev": false,
---
>   "dev": true,
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you did. Can you please elaborate showing exactly what commands you ran? I've had this issue for a couple of weeks and I've never been more frustrated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to solve this issue, go to `.expo/settings.json` and change `dev` to true:

[image]

Credits: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/1210#issuecomment-402347285

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to change `.expo/settings.json` manually.

In the `Expo DevTools` window, which is normally running at `http://localhost:19002`, just toggle `production mode` off.[image]

Comment: or press the `p` key when viewing the console